# Exception is not handled in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using below code to handle exception. But when exception fires, execution is aborted.

```
it('Validate Login form', function () {
     cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {

     done()

     return false
   })

    cy.xpath(repository.discoverMusician.pageHeading);

    cy.validateLoginForm(repository);
})
```

But when exception is fired for `cy.xpath(repository.discoverMusician.pageHeading);`, the execution is aborted and `cy.validateLoginForm(repository);` is not executed.

Can someone please help?

Comment: what do you mean aborted? Is there an error? Also, where does that `done()` come from?

Comment: Execution is terminated when exception occurs. 
I'm refering the below link:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Uncaught-Exceptions

Comment: The `done` callback is passed to `it` callback and should be called to terminate the test. I'm surprised that it doesn't throw since you don't declare it as parameter (are you sure the code you posted is the actual code?). Either way, don't call `done()` if you don't want to terminate your test early.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely caused by calling the `done` callback in your exception handler. The `done` callback is passed to `it` test case's callback, and is meant to be called to terminate test early.

First example - terminate test on error, but make it succeed:

```js
describe('test', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        cy.document().then( doc => {
            doc.body.innerHTML = `
                <button class="btn" onclick="throw new Error('xx')">
                    click me
                </button>
            `;
        });

        Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
            return false;
        });

        cy.log('1');
        cy.get('.btn').click();
        cy.log('2'); // won't run
    });
});
```

second example - don't terminate test on error, but ignore the error instead:

```js
describe('test', () => {
    it('test', (done) => {
        cy.document().then( doc => {
            doc.body.innerHTML = `
                <button class="btn" onclick="throw new Error('xx')">
                    click me
                </button>
            `;
        });

        Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
            done();
            return false;
        });

        cy.log('1');
        cy.get('.btn').click();
        cy.log('2'); // will be run
    });
});
```